# R data.table lapply attributing a list type to a column

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, calculated-columns

This bit of code works fine:

```
dt <- data.table(c(as.integer(98033),as.integer(980341234),as.integer(98033)),c(1,2,3))
dt[,.(count=.N),by=V1]
```

and my problem is in this code block:

```
dt <- dt[,zips:=lapply(V1,fixzip)]
dt[,.(count=.N),by=zips]
```

Which throws

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(count = .N), by = zips) : 
>     The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,1,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (3).

I think it has to do with the lapply assignment, as the environment browser shows

> V1 : int 98033 980341234 98033
>
> zips:List of 3
>
> ..$ : int 98033
>
> ..$ : int 98034
>
> ..$ : int 98033

How do I change that list that got assigned by lapply into a normal column? Or if someone could point me to a better 'R' way to do this that'd be appreciated.

If relevant, the fixzip function looks like:

```
fixzip <- function(zip){
  if(is.finite(zip) == 0){
    return(0)
  }
  if(zip < 10000){
    return(0)
  }
  if(zip > 100000){
    return(as.integer(floor(zip/10000)))
  }
  return(zip)
}
```

Comment: Just use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: If you're only using it on one column, `V1`, write `zip:=fixit(V1)`. Oh, I see, it's not vectorized.

Comment: @Alex self-answer the question so it can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sapply() instead of lapply(). Sapply returns vectors, while lapply returns lists. Thanks to @David Arenburg.